# Binding imperatively

Tags: binding, polymer

Is there a way to set up bindings imperatively. An example use case:

```
var el2 = new MyElement();
el2.myProp = this.$.anotherElement.anotherProp
```

That won't setup a binding, it just assigns the value or object. I'd like to find a way to do something like:

```
el2.myProp.bindTo(this.$.anotherElement.anotherProp)
```

Possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polymer 1.0 does not support this at the moment - as explained by @kevinpschaaf in Github https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1778.

> (comment by @kevinpschaaf)
>
> No, we don't currently support this, outside of dom-bind, which is the
>   only template implementation that late-binds instance children. You
>   can document.createElement('template', 'dom-bind'), then you can
>   dynamically append children with binding annotations to its content,
>   and the bindings will only be evaluated once the dom-bind is attached
>   to the document. See tests here that show this usage of it:
>   https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/test/unit/dom-bind.html#L95
>
> Note that dom-bind does not currently allow binding to outer scope, so
>   it has limited use in custom element templates (it's main use case is
>   for binding between elements in the main document), and that's not
>   likely to change short-term.
>
> We are achieving a lot of performance optimization by baking the
>   binding connections into the prototype at registration time for an
>   element (rather than at instance time), and we haven't built up enough
>   of the machinery to easily allow runtime addition/removal of bindings.

Comment: Thanks - that is unfortunate. Hopefully this will change.

Comment: @max I am rather fond of the `performance optimisation` being achieved - there are other libraries that do what you want, but they do suffer in terms of performance. It's always a trade off - be careful what you wish for.