# Polymer 1.0 Node.bind() - Can I create a binding via javascript instead of double braces?

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way in Polymer 1.0 to set up a binding using javascript like `Node.bind()` did previously?

[Ignore this: Apparently being succinct is not allowed in stackoverflow so I have to write this useless sentence in order to post the question.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: **NO**. Polymer 1.0 currently does not support imperative data-binding.

In 1.0, the data-binding mechanism was completely rewrote, so previous 0.5-ish techniques like `Node.bind('content', new PathObserver(obj, 'path.to.value'));` or

```
Polymer.import(["/elements/x-test.html"], function () {
  var el = document.createElement('x-test');
  el.setAttribute('foo', '{{bar}}');
  document.querySelector("#insertion_point").appendChild(el);
});
```

or `html-echo` does not work.

More info in this SO question: [Binding imperatively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880967/binding-imperatively/30882750)

More info in Github: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1778