# Dart-Polymer 1.0.0-rc.3 instantiate templates

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a bunch of templates such as

```
<template id="test"><span on-click="clickHandler">Click me!</span></template>
```

and I want to instantiate them through code. Basically, these templates are some sort of `prefab` which gets created whenever I need them.

How can I do this?

I expect something like:

```
someElement.append( ($['test'] as TemplateElement).createInstance() );
```

What, if I have to pass arguments to the template?

`<template id="test"><span on-click="clickHandler" item="{{item}}">Click me!`

Comment: I guess you mean Polymer 1.0.0-rc.3?

Comment: Your question looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880967/binding-imperatively/30882750

Comment: yes, my bad. I am currently using `append( instanceTemplate(templateElement))`. Is this the proper way?

Comment: I have no idea, never used anything like that myself yet.

Comment: There seems to be something called `Templatizer` which may prove to be useful?